# change apache current directory of python scripts

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I've setup Apache to work with my Django App using `mod_wsgi` module. Here is the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yaraweb.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost my_server_ip:port>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/YaraWeb

    Alias /static /var/www/YaraWeb/yara/static
    <Directory /var/www/YaraWeb/yara/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/YaraWeb/YaraWeb>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess YaraWeb python-home=/var/www/YaraWeb/venv python-path=/var/www/YaraWeb
    WSGIProcessGroup YaraWeb
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/YaraWeb/YaraWeb/wsgi.py
```

And the structure of `/var/www/YaraWeb` is like this:

```
/var/www/YaraWeb
│   manage.py    
│
└───venv
│   │   bin
│   │   include
│   │   lib
│   │   pip-selfcheck.json
|   |   share
│   
└───yara  => django app
|   │   admin.py
|   │   apps.py
│   |   forms.py
│   |   __init__.py
|   │   main.py
|   │   migrations
│   |   models.py
│   |   static
|   │   templates
│   |   urls.py
│   |   views.py
│    
└───YaraWeb
    │   __init__.py
    │   settings.py
    |   urls.py
    |   wsgi.py
```

Everything works fine and the server is up but the problem is that when log current working directory in my codes, inside `views.py`, it returns `/var/www`, but i expect it to be `/var/www/YaraWeb/`. In other words, i need this snippet of python code to print `/var/www/YaraWeb/`:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd()) # actually prints /var/www/
```

In server codes, there is an extensive usage of relative paths for creating directories. By using relative paths, developer has assumed that all created directories are created inside the project folder i.e. `/var/www/YaraWeb/`, but with current Apache setting, all relative paths try to create directory inside `/var/www/` which may result in overwriting existing files from other projects. Is there any Apache setting that can change this behavior?

Comment: why not use settings.BASE_DIR path from your django settings

Comment: Yes,there shouldn't be any reason to want to change the working directory.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually i have many codes that use relative paths for creating directories and i need these directories to be created inside `/var/www/YaraWeb` but with current setting they are all created inside `/var/www/`. Actually there are lots of code that use relative paths so i need some alternative way instead of refactoring the whole code.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS I have a huge code to deploy on server and the code is using relative paths and i actually don't want to refactor code to use `BASE_DIR` as it takes a lot of time.